# How to get the line position when regex is match?

Tags: c#, regex

I created a regex pattern to find some string in a text file.
I need to know the string position when regex pattern is match.

But I must use `ReadToEnd()`to read the text file, and then use `MatchCollection` to collect all result, so does anyone know if have any method can get string position in the text file.

Comment: I had use this function to try to get the line number, but the result is char count not line number. 
In this case, I want to find out the line number.

Comment: Right, duplicate removed then

Answer (score 1):

have you even searched for this prior to asking your question? Doesn't it also work with readLine like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437716/search-text-file-using-c-sharp-and-display-the-line-number-and-the-complete-line)?

Comment: I've searched, and I know how to record line number when I use "ReadLine()" function, but I want to find out how to record line number when I used "ReadToEnd()" function via streamreader to read all content.

Comment: In the link they use ReadLine() and put that in a loop untill the line is null - -If I'm no mistaking that will actually do the same as ReadToEnd(). Is there any reason why this would not work in your case? - you can use a list<int> to store the index of the line everytime you find an occurence of your pattern inside your loop.