# How to get line number of specific word from HTML file

Tags: c#, html

How to get line number of the `Subtotal` string from HTML file using visual c#.. in below represented the HTML code of the HTML file.

**MY HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%"
               class="sales">
            <!-- Headers -->
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Qty</th>
                <th align="center">Item</th>
                <th align="right">Price</th>
                <th align="right">Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- Rows -->
            <tr class="saleline">
                <td align="left">144</td>
                <td align="left">0002</td>
                <td align="right">5.00</td>
                <td align="right">720.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="saleline">
                <td align="left">8</td>
                <td align="left">0788</td>
                <td align="right">1,200.00</td>
                <td align="right">9,600.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="saleline">
                <td align="left">12</td>
                <td align="left">0013</td>
                <td align="right">15.00</td>
                <td align="right">180.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="saleline">
                <td align="left">144</td>
                <td align="left">120p CR SR 115/=</td>
                <td align="right">115.00</td>
                <td align="right">16,560.00</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Totals -->
            <tr>
                <td align="right"
                    colspan="3">Subtotal</td>
                <td align="right">27,060.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"
                    colspan="3">
                    <b>TOTAL</b>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <b>27,060.00</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"
                    colspan="3">Less Payment</td>
                <td align="right">20,000.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="total">
                <td align="right"
                    colspan="3">
                    <strong>Balance Due</strong>
                </td>
                <td align="right">7,060.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why do you need the line-number? It shouldn't matter. If you want to parse HTML use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would say you're unfair. It's not our place to judge use-cases.

Comment: @Rasmus: i asked why he needs that since it looks like an xy-problem. I didn't judge him.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "It shouldn't matter." - My point is, it matters since that's what he wants to do.

Comment: I tried various method to do that. but it's dosen't work for me.. also i used HtmlAgilitiyPack.. please can you provide some coding example for me?

Comment: @MecDuino: what are you trying to do? I can't help with providing a code sample if you don't tell what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rasmus: sometimes helping people to find a different apporach helps much more than providing a direct solution to the original question. That's called an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm fairly sure that this is one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I might agree with you. We don't know OPs use-case. But there absolutely are valid use-cases for wanting to know which line-number something is present on and the question is simple enough that, provided enough people are interested, the answers will provide several alternatives on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.html");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if ( line.Contains("Subtotal") )
    {
        Console.WriteLine (counter.ToString() + ": " + line);
    }

   counter++;
}

file.Close();
```

[search text file using c# and display the line number and the complete line that contains the search keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437716/search-text-file-using-c-sharp-and-display-the-line-number-and-the-complete-line)